# Merging Nodes in D3 Force Layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, merge, force-layout, graph-visualization

I am not sure if this can be done but I feel like logically I have the functionality programmed. I am trying to make it so a user can select multiple nodes and then hit the `merge` button and all of those nodes get merged (into a new node called `MergedNode#`). This new node will inherit all of the links of all the nodes that were merged. This node should also be able to `unmerge` which will destroy the `MergedNode` and restore all of the nodes/links within.

Here is a code snippet where I am doing most of the `merge` handling (ignoring `unmerge` for now).

```
function mergeNode() {
    mergedNodesStore = [];
    console.log("Attempting to merge nodes.");
    // Check if at least 2 nodes are selected.
    if (selectedNodes.length < 2) {
        alert("Must select at least 2 or more nodes.");
    }
    else {
        // Iterating through each of the selected nodes.
        for (var i = 0; i < selectedNodes.length; i++) {
            mergedNodesStore.push[selectedNodes[i]];

            // Iterates through each of the edges to apply the old links to new merged node.
            for (var j = 0; j < edges.length; j++) {
                var mergedEdge;
                if (selectedNodes[i].data.id === edges[j].data.source) {
                    mergedEdge = edges[j].data.target;
                    edges.push({
                        source: "MergedNode" + mnCount,
                        target: mergedEdge,
                        data: selectedNodes[i].data
                    });
                }
                else if (selectedNodes[i].data.id === edges[j].data.target) {
                    mergedEdge = edges[j].data.source;
                    edges.push({
                        source: "MergedNode" + mnCount,
                        target: mergedEdge,
                        data: selectedNodes[i].data
                    });
                }
            }

            // Remove the merge nodes from the nodes array.
            selectedNodes[i].removed = true;
            nodes.splice(nodes.indexOf(selectedNodes[i]), 1);
            spliceLinksForNode(selectedNodes[i]);
        }

        // Push the "MergeNode" to the mergeNodes array.
        mergedNodes.push({
            id: "MergedNode" + mnCount,
            label: "MergedNode" + mnCount,
            childrenNodes: mergedNodesStore
        });
        mnCount++;
    }
    insertMergeNodes();
}

function insertMergeNodes() {

    // pushes the NODE attributes in the JSON to the nodes array.
    mergedNodes.forEach(function(n) {
        // if node already exists it does not get pushed to the nodes array.e
        if (!(n.data.id in nodesHash)) {
            nodesHash[n.data['id']] = n;
            nodes.push({
                data: n.data,
                selected: n.selected,
                removed: n.removed
            });
        }
        else console.log(n.data.id + "already exists.");
    })

    // sets the source and target to use id instead of index
    edges.forEach(function(e) {
        var sourceNode = nodes.filter(function(n) {
                    return n.data.id === e.data.source;
                })[0],
                targetNode = nodes.filter(function(n) {
                    return n.data.id === e.data.target;
                })[0];

        // push the EDGE attributes in the JSON to the edges array.
        edges.push({
            source: sourceNode,
            target: targetNode,
            data: e.data
        });
    });

    force
            .nodes(mergeNodes)
            .links(edges)
    update();
}
```

However, when selecting then merging the nodes, no new nodes are being created but the selected nodes are successfully being removed. Also, I am receiving odd text overwriting in the labels when doing this (seperate issue but ignoring for now - [Remove Text from Nodes in d3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30335368/remove-text-from-nodes-in-d3)).

My code can be found here: http://bl.ocks.org/joeycf/f021e60bb38846dcfaf2
Double Click to `Select`/`Deselect` and the merge is done by clicking on the button.

Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093130)?

Comment: Yes. I have seen that example although the issue I am having is a little different from that approach. The "children" nodes in that example are already linked and have the standard properties needed. For mine, the user is selecting any multiple nodes to merge (which are each just stored as objects) and the new node will have to link to every single link that the other nodes had.