# How to remove D3 link text from visualization

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

When nodes within my force directed visualization are clicked any child nodes (and their associated links) are toggled on/off. However, the text which acts as a label for these links is not removed when its associated child node and link are removed. See below:

[image]

Here is the relevant section of code, with the last line (`linkText.exit.remove()`) being my attempt at removing these labels:

```
var nodes = flatten(data);
var links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);

var path = vis.selectAll('path.link')
  .data(links, function(d) {
    return d.target.id;
  });

path.enter().insert('svg:path')
  .attr({
    class: 'link',
    id: function(d) {
      return 'text-path-' + d.target.id;
    },
    'marker-end': 'url(#end)'
  })
  .style('stroke', '#ccc');

var linkText = vis.selectAll('g.link-text').data(links);

linkText.enter()
  .append('text')
    .append('textPath')
      .attr('xlink:href', function(d) {
        return '#text-path-' + d.target.id;
      })
      .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
      .attr('startOffset', '50%')
      .text(function(d) {return d.target.customer_id});

path.exit().remove();

linkText.exit().remove();
```

Here is a link to a block as well: http://blockbuilder.org/MattDionis/5f966a5230079d9eb9f4

Comment: What about adding the identifier function to the join you perform when you define `linkText`? Try using `.data(links, function (d) { return d.target.id; })` instead of just `.data(links)`, just like you did for the `path` selection variable.

Comment: @jrsala Good catch, and I thought that would have solved it, but it did not. What's odd to me is that although I set `linkText = vis.selectAll('g.link-text').data(links)`, there are no `g` elements with class `link-text` in my DOM. Rather there are simply `text` nodes with `textPath` inside. I'm wondering if this is why it cannot properly remove `g.link-text` elements, because they somehow do not exist.

Comment: OH, right... you never actually create `g` elements with class `link-text`!! So when you run your update function once more, the selection is empty.
Use `linkText = vis.selectAll('g.link-text').data(links); linkText.enter().append('g').attr('class', 'link-text').append('text')... bla bla`. It has happened to me so many times... I know it's not DRY, but that's how D3 works, and that's why it's surprising, because D3 is supposed to be DRY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out no `g` element with class `link-text` ever gets created, so the exit selection is empty.

Replace

```
linkText.enter()
    .append('text')
        .append('textPath')
        .attr('xlink:href', function(d) {
            return '#text-path-' + d.target.id;
        });
```

with

```
linkText.enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'link-text')
        .append('text')
            .append('textPath')
            .attr('xlink:href', function(d) {
                return '#text-path-' + d.target.id;
            });
```

Also, it's necessary to specify the identifier function for `linkText` just like you did for `path`, otherwise d3 cannot match the missing data with an exit selection!

```
var linkText = vis.selectAll('g.link-text').data(
    links,
    function (d) { return d.target.id; }
);
```